# Chrome does not have enough memory to display this webpage

Tags: google-chrome

I have a d3 browser application which loads data over time (live updates per second) and displays it on the graph.
Lately I've ran over this problem where my chrome tab crashes after some random time, with the uninformative error: "Chrome ran out of memory to display this page", even though my computer has plenty of spare RAM to use.

Like I said, this error comes after some random time, not related to the amount of data loaded...

Is there any way I could debug and know why Chrome has thrown that error, and what are the probable causes?

I'm not 100% sure, but the tab seems to crash after switching to it from an other tab (not related to the application).

Thanks

Comment: chrome is not opensource. FIll a bugreport and/or you can debug chromium.

Comment: How could I debug with chromium? Sorry, I've never used chromium before.

Comment: Chromium is the open source browser project chrome is based on so if it happens in chrome it might have in Chromium, and since its open I'm guessing they are saying you can debug it yourself rather than waiting on an answer from Google about Chrome